# Call ldap security login and then additional custom action from same link

Tags: java, spring, jsp, authentication, spring-security

I have a webapp that needs to login twice when the user logs in : once with an ldap authentication (used spring security) and then I want to auto login using the original custom login system.

To login to the original system, I've got a login.xhtml page having this :

```
<h:inputText value="#{loginForm.username}" id="username"/>
<h:inputSecret value="#{loginForm.password}" id="password"/>
(...)
<h:commandButton action="#{loginForm.login}"  value="Connexion"/>
```

LoginForm.login does the work I need and returns "first_page" so that the user can enter the application.

Now that I added a login.jsp page for spring security with :

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
<input name="j_username">
<input type="password" name="j_password" />
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

The user is redirected to the first page without calling LoginForm.login.

How can I call both login action, passing username and password to both of them ?

Thank you